# How to manage number of Lists Generally?

Tags: c#, generics

I got to manage number of Lists but not sure this is right solution.
It looks hard to maintenance...

Are there any Solutions for doing that more generally?

```
List<myAClass> A
List<myBClass> B
List<myCClass> C
...

public void init<T>(this T target)
{
    switch(target.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].Name)
    {
        case "myAClass":
            'do Z for A'
            break;

        case "myBClass":
            'do Z for B'
            break;

        case "myCClass":
            'do Z for C'
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review. try codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you for your opinion. Have Edited

Comment: Your code is not generic - you have different implementations for different types, so overloads would be a more appropriate solution, however without understanding why `init` is generic a decent answer is not possible.

Comment: If you are doing `Z` for every class, why have a switch statement in the first place?

Comment: Also, what does `Z` do?  Can _it_ be generic (or at least covariant)?

Answer (score 0):

Usually in these cases I try to create a map (aka `Dictionary`). Kind of like this:

```
    Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> myMap = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>
    {
        {typeof(myAClass), list =>{ /* YOUR METHOD/LAMBDA/ETC HERE  */ }},
        {typeof(myBClass), list =>{ /* YOUR METHOD/LAMBDA/ETC HERE  */ }},
        {typeof(myCClass), list =>{ /* YOUR METHOD/LAMBDA/ETC HERE  */ }},
    };

    public void Init<T>(T target)
    {
        if (myMap.ContainsKey(typeof (T)))
        {
            myMap[typeof (T)](target);
        }
    }
```

Note: I haven't tried compiling this code, and also there
s a slight code smell with how I'm passing in the `List<T>` as a plain old object (so you'll need to cast it back again). In my defense, this is the 3-minute answer...   ;-)